# Проблемы после удаления compiz

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет. Ubuntu 14.04 Решил, что compiz мне не нужен и снёс его полностью командой `sudo apt-get purge compiz compiz-plugins-main-default libcompizconfig0`

Пропало верхнее и боковое меню, перестал вызываться терминал. Зашёл через текстовый, кое как поставил compiz обратно, т.к Ubuntu очень долго ругалась что пакеты для установки compiz повреждены (пробовал ставить metacity была та же ерунда с пакетами, хотя её я не сносил). Вроде как наконец compiz встал(некоторые пакеты на которые он ругался, что не установлены, на самом деле стояли, я их сносил и ставил опять, когда все переустановил, компиз перестал ругаться). Перезагрузил машину, но ничего не поменялось.

Попробовал через compiz --replace запустить, но выдает : Info:Loading plugin: core Info:Starting plugin: core Info:Couldn't open display Info: Stopping plugin: core Info: Unloading plugin: core

$DISPLAY ничего не выдает, пробовал в него устанавливать и 0.0 и 0.1, ничего не меняется aptitude показывает, что compiz установлен gnom-shell поставил, ничего не поменялось Поставил gdm, поменялось оформление при входе. И если раньше вход был автоматический и я сразу входил на голый стол без менюшек, то теперь показывается окно логина, но после ввода пароля ничего не меняется, просто все окно обновляется и опять предлагают войти в аккаунт (пароль правильный и он на него не ругается). Имя папки ~/.config поменял, ничего не изменилось. Имя файла ~/.config/monitors.xml тоже поменял, результата нет Поставил metacity, сделал metacity --replace выдало: Window manager error: Unable to open X display

В more /var/log/Xorg.0.log варнинги про отсутствие директорий /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, /usr/.../X11/100dpi, /usr/.../X11/75dpi. Error-ов нет

rm ~/.Xauthority - Ничего не поменяло

dpkg -l | grep xserver выдаёт вот такое https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUqawKOxWPwCC80gHEJoVeT8HyKGt8YE/view

Вроде всё, больше идей у меня нет. В инете ничего больше тоже не нашел. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете